# Alter table to add dynamic columns based off some previously selected query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to alter a table and add columns with a dynamic name/data type based off some previously select query?

The pseudo equivalent for what I'm looking to do in SQL would be:

```
foreach row in tableA
{
  alter tableB add row.name row.datatype
}
```

This is for SQL Server.

Comment: What are you **really** trying to do here? This sounds like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: Sample data, and expected results would be nice, as well as your attempt(s) and./or research as well as a clear question to go with it would be nice.

Comment: like so: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9e6ac026b64dd4fdfb70667a91b92999

Comment: Once you choose this path, you will find your attempts to use such a table in tsql code **FAR** more difficult. Think twice about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you can do this with dynamic sql. Something along these lines:

```
Declare @SQL1  nvarchar(4000)
SELECT @SQL1=N'ALTER TABLE mytable'+NCHAR(13)+NCHAR(10)
+N' ADD COLUMN '+ my_new_column_name + ' varchar(25)'+NCHAR(13)+NCHAR(10)
-- SELECT LEN(@SQL1), @SQL1
EXECUTE (@SQL1)
```

Apart from the fact that this is messy, error prone, a security risk, requires high authorization to execute and needs multiple variables for batches bigger than 4000 characters, it is usually also a bad idea from a design point of view (depending on when/why you are doing this).

Comment: The query probably will work, but it does not check if table/column exist. Also it does not check number of columns and their sizes table already has.
Anyway, adding columns dynamically is crazy idea as jumping from a cliff.

Comment: If the OP wanted to check for existance, this could be done by querying sys.tables (object_id) and sys.columns. I presumed he would know in advance whether or not the column should be added.

I agree with your "crazy" comment. It can be fun to jump off a cliff, but should not be taken lightly.

Comment: If you really want to help the person, explain him the craziness or at least show him how to do some protection.

Comment: There is not enough information to assess what protections (if any) are viable.

Comment: IMHO Any schema changes via application is usually a nightmare for everybody, including users, developers and DBAs

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do this with dynamic sql.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22029900)

Comment: This provides a suggestion that leads to a solution, and is therefore a valid answer.   It is neither a critique, nor a request for clarification.  Notice that the actual question is "Is it possible..?".

Comment: A suggestion that leads to an answer should be posted as a comment. An actual answer should be posted as an answer.

Comment: @AleksG I don't know where you got that impression.   It's not the consensus on Meta.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318020/so-this-is-an-answer

Comment: The opposite is not the consensus either

Comment: Very good answer. It is like for question "Can I jump from that cliff?" answer "Yes, YOU can." I'd add more: "You have to!!!"